# How should chmod and chown be used together?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, chown

I recently sold my mac, and before doing so I put its files on an external HDD. Now I'm using Linux to move those files to a larger HDD, but some folders still retained some residual mac permissions, so I want to make all the HDD's files and directories as openly accessable as possible. So I opened up the terminal and executed [no runtime errors]:

```
su; cd /file_system_root; chown -R nicholas:users .; chmod -R a=rw .;
```

But now as I'm logged into XFCE as nicholas, I get "permission denied" when I try to access folders in the root directory (i.e. "/unaccessable_folder"), and I'm confused as to why.

I've tried ejecting and re-mounting the HDD, and explicitly chown'ing and chmod'ing the folder that the HDD is mounted ("/run/media/nicholas/hdd_id"), but neither affected the problem.

(I'm running openSUSE 12.3; the drive is ext4 formatted, 3TB, and has a "lost+found" folder in its root directory.)

Comment: What permissions do the files have? Show us the output of `ls -l` on a few of them. Also, how are you mounting the drive? Permissions can be set on mount as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders need have to have the executable bit set for you to be able to open them. This explains the details better then I could. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt